# Dojo Cache - Tree - Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function

Tags: caching, dojo, tree

I am trying to use a data store cache with a tree.

I am getting Uncaught TypeError: `object is not a function error.`

I have tested the data and it is being pulled correctly.

I have checked the JSON and it is also correct.

Where am I going wrong?

```
    require(["dojo/store/JsonRest"
        , "dojo/store/Memory"
        , "dojo/store/Cache"
        , "dojo/json"
        , "dijit/tree/ObjectStoreModel"
        , "dijit/Tree"
        , "dojo/domReady!"],
        function (JsonRest, Memory, Cache, ObjectStoreModel, Tree) {

            var restStore = new JsonRest({ target: "/DataStore/", idProperty: "id" });

            var memoryStore = new Memory({
                idProperty: "id",
                getChildren: function (object) {
                    return this.query({ parent: object.id });
                }
            });

            var store = new Cache(restStore, memoryStore);

            store.query({ type: "index" }).forEach(function (item) {
                console.log(item.name);
            });

            var docModel = new ObjectStoreModel(
                {
                    store: store,
                    getRoot: function (onItem) {
                        this.store.get("index").then(onItem);
                    },
                    mayHaveChildren: function (object) {
                        return object.type === "folder" || object.type === "root";
                    }
                });

            var docTree = new Tree({
                model: docModel,
                onOpenClick: true,
                onClick: function (item) {
                    if (item.type == "link") {
                        OpenLink(item.link);
                    }
                },
                persist: false
            }, "divTree");

            docTree.startup();

        });
```

Comment: This is the JSON that is being returned by the target URL /DataStore/

[
{
name: "Folders",
id: "index",
type: "index",
root: true
},
{
name: "Workspaces",
id: "WKSP",
parent: "index",
type: "folder"
},
{
name: "General Public Folders",
id: "GEN",
parent: "index",
type: "folder"
},
{
name: "BIRM Public Folders",
id: "BIRM",
parent: "index",
type: "folder"
},
{
name: "LA Public Folders",
id: "LA",
parent: "index",
type: "folder"
},
{
name: "SECURE Public Folders",
id: "SEC",
parent: "index",
type: "folder"
},
{
name: "My Matters",
id: "MMAT",
parent: "index",
type: "folder"
}
]

Answer (score 1):

This has to do how `Cache` works. The first time `store.get()` is called, it uses the `JsonRest` store which returns a `Promise`. A `Promise` has a `then()` function so there is no problem. The next time it's called, it uses the `Memory` store which returns your JavaScript object itself. Your JavaScript object has no `then()` function, so an error is thrown. This can be fixed by surrounding the `store.get()` in a `when()`.

Try changing

```
this.store.get("index").then(onItem);
```

to

```
when(this.store.get("index")).then(onItem);
```

Take a look [here](https://www.sitepen.com/blog/2013/08/27/dojo-faq-why-dont-object-stores-always-return-a-promise/) for more details.